# Can we simplify this series of negative numbers? Or is it the best I'm going to get? Also, do powers over negative numbers commute/associate?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have a sequence

$$a_n(-1)^{-\frac{1}{2}n(n-1)}, \ n \in \mathbb{N}$$

This produces a sequence like

$$a_0, a_1, -a_2, -a_3, a_4, a_5, -a_6, -a_7, a_8 ...$$

I'm not sure what you call this kind of alternation, but is there a way to simplify it in terms of some $a_{n_i} - a_{n_j}$ and then further to some $a_k - a_{l}$?

I also have an additional question. I thought I could simplify this by assuming that

$$(-1)^{ab} = ((-1)^{a})^{b} = ((-1)^{b})^{a}$$

but got conflicting results when I did that. Did I make an algebra mistake or is that generally a false statement for $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: The question about the powers, you need to be extremely careful with powers when negative or nonreal bases are involved.  It is false that $(-1)^{ab}$ is always equal to $((-1)^a)^b$.  Take $a=2,b=\frac{1}{2}$ for a counterexample.  If you were to guarantee that $a,b$ are both integers then it might be fine.

Comment: The question about the sequence, I don't understand what you are asking for here.  It already seems quite simple already.  What sort of simplification do you expect to see?  As for what to call it... there doesn't have to be a canonical name for it.  You can use your own words to describe it.  I would probably call this an "alternating every-other sequence" if I had to, but would be sure to give an explanation what I meant.

Comment: For **positive** values of $x$, it's always true that $x^{ab} = (x^a)^b = (x^b)^a$. Alternatively, for any $x$, if $a$ and $b$ are integers, you're okay.

Answer (score 1):

The only obvious simplification is to remove the negation in the exponent, as it's doing nothing:
$$
(-1)^{-\frac12 n(n-1)} 
= (-1)^{(-1) \cdot \frac12 n(n-1)} 
= \bigl( (-1)^{-1} \bigr)^{\frac12 n(n-1)}
= (-1)^{\frac12 n(n-1)}.
$$
These manipulations are valid as both factors $(-1)$ and $\binom{n}{2} = \frac12 n(n-1)$ are integers for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

---

As an alternative way to represent the sign pattern
$+, +, -, -, +, +, -, -, \dots$ we can observe that this pattern has a period of $4$, and any formula like $(-1)^{\varepsilon_n}$, where
$$
\varepsilon_n = \begin{cases} 
\mathrm{even} & n \equiv 0, 1 \mod 4 \\
\mathrm{odd} & n \equiv 2, 3 \mod 4 
\end{cases}
$$
works. One alternative possibility involves rounding using the floor function:
$$
\varepsilon_n = \bigl\lfloor \tfrac12 n \bigr\rfloor,
$$
but it's not clear that
$$
(-1)^{\bigl\lfloor \tfrac12 n \bigr\rfloor} 
$$
is any *better.*

---

By messing around, we can also fit a periodic curve, such as a sinusoid to the sequence of signs, but I doubt that you want a formula like this:
$$
\sigma_n = \sqrt{2} \cos 
\biggl( \frac{\pi}{2}\Bigl(n - \frac12 \Bigr) \!\biggr) 
$$

[image: Sinusoidal sign sequence.]